# Wordpress plugin development - error exporting .csv

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wordpress plugin and I need to export some stuff from the database.

```
    <?php
ob_start();
global $wpdb;
$statements = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_paypal_statements ORDER BY id DESC" );

if (isset($_POST["export"])) 
{
    ob_end_clean();

    $csv = "User ID, PayPal Email, Amount \n";//Column headers
        foreach ($statements as $record)
        {
            $csv .= $record->id . ',' . $record->paypal_email. ',' . $record->amount . "\n"; //Append data to csv
        }
        $csv_handler = fopen("php://output", 'w');
        fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
        fclose ($csv_handler);

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    exit();
}
```

I'm getting that file full of html source code. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
<!--[if IE 8]>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8 wp-toolbar"  lang="en-US">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<![endif]-->                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wp-toolbar"  lang="en-US">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<!--<![endif]-->                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
<head>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
<title> &lsaquo; WP Plugin Factory London &#8212; WordPress</title>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
<script type="text/javascript">
```

That's how my code looks and I fail to see what is wrong here. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: lol sorry! i get a csv file full of html source code

Comment: "HTML source code" is rather vague ... What's the content?

Comment: Hi, i added an example to the main post.